# how to train a single agent with two or more behaviors at the same time?

Tags: unity-game-engine, machine-learning

I am using unity ML agetns to train my agents, now i want to use two behaviors, one for navigation, another for decision making. I want the agent to train on these two behaviors simultaneously, i understand that i have to define two behaviors in YAML file, but while writing the C# script to give the observations and receive the actions how do i check which observations to pass to which behavior?

I have tried to search on the web, but has not found anything.

Thank you for helping.